# What can I do to increase my fame?

Tags: state-of-decay

At the end of each day, I receive a message indicating that my daily influence was limited by the amount of fame I have. This also shows up in my journal;

[image]

What actions can I take to increase my fame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fame represents how well known and respected the player is by the Community. Unlike Influence, which fluctuates with use, Fame is much more static and only changes when the player completes specific actions.

The symbol for Fame is a crown inside a circle.

There are three main ways to gain Fame:

#### Leveling up survivors

- For each level of Basic Skill (Cardio, Wits, Fighting, Shooting) and Weapon Specialization, the player earns 1 Fame.
- The maximum Fame a single character can gain is 30 (24 Fame for improving basic skills and 6 for improving one specialization skill. Improving personal skills does *NOT* gain Fame)
- In the Breakdown DLC, each level of Basic Skill or Weapon Specialization gives 4 Fame instead of 1.

#### Completing missions

The following storyline missions gives Fame rewards (Some missions give it as a default reward, others require the player to complete certain challenges).

- The Voice on the Radio (100 - Social Network)
- The Vet Clinic (25 - Flawless)
- Lily's Brother (25 - Slaughter)
- The old Farmhouse (25 - Slaughter)
- Indefensible (25 - Slaughter)
- Civic Duty (25 - Slaughter)
- Trouble at the Courthouse (25 - Slaughter)
- Army Activity (25 - Savior)
- Insubordination (25 - Savior)
- Sgt. Erik Tan (25 - Slaughter)
- The Armory (25 - Slaughter)
- The Wall (25 - Slaughter)

The following repeatable mission gives Fame rewards

- Friendly Survivors (25 - Social Network)

#### Build Facilities

- After an advice from Lily pops up (e.g. Advice: Build Medical Area), building the Facility in question rewards the player with 25 Fame (Savior).

---

<sup>Source: [State of Decay Wiki, "**Fame**" article](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Fame)</sup>